# How to create multiple DStream for kinesis on pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-kinesis

In the example https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/external/kinesis-asl, both scala and java are creating multiple Dstreams manually

```
val sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName("KinesisWordCountASL")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConfig, batchInterval)

// Create the Kinesis DStreams
val kinesisStreams = (0 until numStreams).map { i =>
  KinesisInputDStream.builder
    .streamingContext(ssc)
    .streamName(streamName)
    .endpointUrl(endpointUrl)
    .regionName(regionName)
    .initialPosition(new Latest())
    .checkpointAppName(appName)
    .checkpointInterval(kinesisCheckpointInterval)
    .storageLevel(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)
    .build()
}

// Union all the streams
val unionStreams = ssc.union(kinesisStreams)
```

But for python, there is only one DStream being created

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKinesisWordCountAsl")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
appName, streamName, endpointUrl, regionName = sys.argv[1:]
lines = KinesisUtils.createStream(
    ssc, appName, streamName, endpointUrl, regionName, InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, 2)
```

When manually creating multiple Dstream on python,

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKinesisWordCountAsl")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
appName, streamName, endpointUrl, regionName = sys.argv[1:]
dstreams = [KinesisUtils.createStream(
    ssc, appName, streamName, endpointUrl, regionName, InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, 2) for i in range(num_streams)]
lines = sc.union(dstreams)
```

This will throw an error

```
ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once;
```

Anyone knows how to replicate the java/scala examples on creating DStreams? Thanks

Comment: Are you receiving records? I have no errors but am not receiving any records.

Comment: Yes, but I only use one DStream. For some reason InitialPositionInStream.LATEST does not work for me but InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON does.

Answer (score 0):

We can combine multiple streams in python also. We need to use [union](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.streaming.StreamingContext.union.html#pyspark.streaming.StreamingContext.union) function available on StreamingContext class.

If you look into your code, you are calling union method on SparkContext variable i.e sc instead of that use StreamingContext valriable i.e `lines = ssc.union(dstreams)`